# Getting Notice Notice: Use of undefined constant sales_flat_order_status_history - assumed 'sales_flat_order_status_history'

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, custom

I have created below collection query in my custom external magento page--

```
<?php 

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
umask(0);
Mage::init('default');
Mage::app();

$start_date='2016-03-01';  
$end_date='2016-04-01';   

$orderCollection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
try{                    
    $orderCollection->getSelect()->join(array('order_history'=> sales_flat_order_status_history), "main_table.entity_id=order_history.parent_id WHERE (order_history.entity_name = 'invoice' OR order_history.entity_name = 'shipment') AND order_history.status = 'complete' AND order_history.created_at >= '".$start_date."' and order_history.created_at < '".$end_date."' ", array('order_history.parent_id'));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

this query gives me following error--

**Notice: Use of undefined constant sales_flat_order_status_history - assumed 'sales_flat_order_status_history'**

I don't know, what wrong there ? Can anybody found out the problem there?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use single or double quotearray('order_history'=> 'sales_flat_order_status_history') in your code.

Comment: Hello Nits, please check my comment for Neklo's Answer.

Comment: I have checked you script, remove date filter or enter proper date in you collection filter so you will get record.

Comment: @nits, I cant remove date filter its very important, can you tell me what proper date I should entered since Db stores date in same format. And what you have tried?

Comment: I have checked  your script remove date filter in my local setup its working fine,  So enter proper date  (which contain data from your order) in you collection filter, you will get record.

Comment: I have checked by using $start_date='2016-03-01 00:00:00'; and $end_date='2016-04-01 00:00:00';. still getting same problem. Can you please put your code what you have tried.

Comment: did you check in your database, data available between 2016-03-01 00:00:00 and 2016-04-01 00:00:00?

Comment: yeah, of course..I checked it. there are around 470 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **sales_flat_order_status_history** to **'sales_flat_order_status_history'** and you will get

> SELECT `main_table`.*, `order_history`.`parent_id` FROM
>   `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN
>   `sales_flat_order_status_history` AS `order_history` ON
>   main_table.entity_id=order_history.parent_id WHERE
>   (order_history.entity_name = 'invoice' OR order_history.entity_name =
>   'shipment') AND order_history.status = 'complete' AND
>   order_history.created_at >= '2016-03-01' and order_history.created_at
>   < '2016-04-01'

Comment: Hello Neklo, if I do like you suggested, and then I try this echo count($orderCollection) it prints nothing. and If I wanna iterate this collection using foreach(), it also does not work.

Comment: try add 
`echo $orderCollection->getSelect();`
after join in try catch and you will see query then try exequte it in mysql